# How Can We Create a Streamilt App to Run From Giuthub?

Tags: python, python-3.x, github, streamlit

I came across this URL today, which seems to describe how to create a Streamlit app that runs from Github.

https://towardsdatascience.com/publish-your-streamlit-apps-in-the-cloud-3ac5a5fe3d51

I have an loan classifier app that runs perfectly fine in Spyder. My file structure, in the folder, looks like this...

[image]

I added the relevant files to GitHub, and the setup looks like this.

[image]

How can I run the app, and/or, make it dynamic, so any random person can interact with the web interface. Or, if I am totally missing the point, please let me know. The app runs perfectly fine on my desktop, using Spyder, in Anaconda, but I can't figure out how to make it run on GitHub.

Comment: The compute in this tutorial is provided by Streamlit, which downloads your project code from your GitHub repository. Have you read that section of the tutorial yet?

Comment: Have a look at this https://docs.streamlit.io/streamlit-cloud/get-started/deploy-an-app.